# Entity Framework primary key name

Tags: entity-framework

I have created an entity model. I want to get the primary key name (i.e. property name) when I pass the entity name at runtime. Is it possible?

Comment: Column name or property name? Why do you need column name?

Comment: yes i mean property name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with entity type:

```
var objectSet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<YourEntityType>();
var keyNames = objectSet.EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Select(k => k.Name);
```

or with entity type name:

```
var workspace = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
var entityType = workspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.CSpace)
                          .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == yourEntityTypeName);
var keyNames = entityType.KeyMembers.Select(k => k.Name);
```